# How to create a json with mixed type matrix in c#

Tags: c#

I need to create a json structure that has a 2 dimensional matrix with mixed types (int and double) in it. Size of the matrix as well as actual positions of elements varies from instance to instance. It would generally look something like this:

```
"matrix": [
[1.1, 2.2, 5, 9],
[2, 2.2, 5, 1.1],
[2, 3, 5, 9]
]
```

I wanted to create the class with structure corresponding my intended structure and use Newtonsoft json serializer to create a json from it and it works save for this matrix. There are examples on serialization of mixed types out there but they all deal with arrays with pre-defined formats like this:

```
[
["value1", 1],
["value2", 2],
["value3", 3],
]
```

How can an array without a pre-defined format like this be created in c#?

Comment: Can you have every element as `double`?

Comment: Surely the "int" is just a special case of a double with a 0 for the fraction.  You can't tell the difference after it is all converted to a json string.

Comment: How you want to access your mixed data from C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way:

```
List<List<object>> objs = new List<List<object>>();
objs.Add(new List<object>() { "value1", 1, 204.23 });
```

With a list you don't have a fixed length, and by declaring the type as object you can put every type.